# boost::lockfree::queue doesn't seem to free memory though destructor on every collection object is invoked

Tags: c++, boost, lock-free

The problem here is, boost::lockfree::queue doesn't free memory once it is allocated. Why freelist nodes are not returned to OS? destructors on individual collection objects are invoked.

I want to fix the memory issue, Any suggestions on lockfree queue memory allocation. Anything I am doing wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

struct Record
{
    char str[128];

    Record(const char* rec)
    {
        memset(this->str, 0, sizeof(this->str));
        strcpy_s(this->str, rec);
    }

    ~Record()
    {
        cout << "~Record " << this->str << endl;
    }

    Record& operator= (const Record& rec)
    {
        if (this == &rec)
        {
            return *this;
        }

        memset(this->str, 0, sizeof(this->str));
        strcpy_s(this->str, rec.str);
        return *this;
    }
};

typedef boost::lockfree::queue<Record*, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true>> RecordsQueue;

RecordsQueue Records(10000);

class MyClass
{
public:

    void FillThread()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Record *rec = new Record(to_string(i).c_str());
            Records.push(rec);
            i++;
        };
    }

    void ProcessThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Record *rec;
            Records.pop(rec);
            {
                cout << "Record " << rec->str << endl;
                delete rec;
            }
        };
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    boost::thread* thread1, *thread2;

    MyClass myObj;

    thread1 = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClass::FillThread, myObj));
    HANDLE threadHandle1 = thread1->native_handle();
    SetThreadPriority(threadHandle1, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);

    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));

    thread2 = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClass::ProcessThread, myObj));
    HANDLE threadHandle2 = thread2->native_handle();
    SetThreadPriority(threadHandle2, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);

    thread1->join();
    thread2->join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are pushing more records onto the queue than there are spaces available. This overwrites previously owned spaces and causes them not to be released in the future. Try changing the FillThread to a for loop.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. Records which are pushed they deleted by another thread almost instantaneously.

Record 0
~Record 0
Record 1
~Record 1
Record 2
~Record 2
Record 3
~Record 3
Record 4
~Record 4
Record 5
~Record 5
Record 6
~Record 6

Comment: @user3924882 lockfree::queue::push just returns false if there is now space left, and your records allocated with `new` are never deleted in this case.

Comment: I was mistaken on how push works, but luckily the problem stems from the same area of code.